Authentication Issue with connecting to powerBI using OAuth authentication
I am connecting to a synapse SQL database from powerBI, this is using a data gateway. If I use SQL authentication, it works fine however if i change it to OAuth authentication, I get the error below.
Unable to create connection for the following reason: Unable to connect to the data source. Either the data source is inaccessible, a connection timeout occurred, or the data source credentials are invalid. Please verify the data source configuration and contact a data source administrator to troubleshoot this issue.

Details:

Microsoft SQL: Reason: An instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Connection was denied since Deny Public Network Access is set to Yes (https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-settings#deny-public-network-access). To connect to this server, use the Private Endpoint from inside your virtual network (https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/sql-database/sql-database-private-endpoint-overview#how-to-set-up-private-link-for-azure-sql-database).

Please have this information handy if you choose to create a support ticket.
Cluster URI: https://api.powerbi.com
Status code: 400


According to this you should use either the Database or the Microsoft account authentication for synapse sql database. How did you enter the OAuth authentication credentials?

Also, why and how you using a data gateway to connect to Synapse? Do you mean VPN Gateway?

According to this MS document you should use either the Database or the Microsoft account authentication for synapse SQL database. Select Microsoft account, sign in with your AD user and connect it as shown below:

It will connect successfully as shown below:

Unable to create connection for the following reason: Unable to connect to the data source. Either the data source is inaccessible, a connection timeout occurred, or the data source credentials are invalid. Please verify the data source configuration and contact a data source administrator to troubleshoot this issue.

Details:

Microsoft SQL: Reason: An instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Connection was denied since Deny Public Network Access is set to Yes (https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-settings#deny-public-network-access). To connect to this server, use the Private Endpoint from inside your virtual network (https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/sql-database/sql-database-private-endpoint-overview#how-to-set-up-private-link-for-azure-sql-database).

Please have this information handy if you choose to create a support ticket.
Cluster URI: https://api.powerbi.com
Status code: 400

Public network was disabled for your synapse network. That may be the reason to get above error. Enable public access for your synapse workspace or if want to use private network use private endpoints. By following this document configure private endpoint to connect synapse database to Power BI desktop. For more information you refer similar SO thread.

@learner Please check if the solution helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
